# Php/mysql: Handling empty sql result in php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've got, in this case, 4 radio buttons in a form. In a previous step a user gets to choose between options (like A, B, C, D) that include different radios being selected. Eg: Choose A and radio 1 is selected, and so on. This choice is saved in mysql as

```
// If B:

Customer Prod Group Chosen
12345    1    1     0
12345    2    1     1
12345    3    1     0
12345    4    1     0
```

For later use in some other weird IT system, I need to save the non selected as `0`.
Later the user can visit this page again. I then check the database to mark the correct radio as `checked`.

---

**Problem**

> The user must not make the initial choice.

Since the user **must not** make a choice (A, B...) I'm having trouble with the sql query when it's returning an empty result (no choices found). I save the sql result to `$p` in this case and then check if it's 1 or 0/empty.

```
<input type="button" <?= empty($p[0])?'':'checked';?> />
<input type="button" <?= empty($p[1])?'':'checked';?> />
<input type="button" <?= empty($p[2])?'':'checked';?> />
<input type="button" <?= empty($p[3])?'':'checked';?> />
```

This results in the first 3 radios being checked.

Any idea how to tackle this?
I somehow need to check if the sql entry is `1` (chosen), `0` (not chosen)or not present at all.

The SQL is just a simple query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT chosen 
FROM choices 
WHERE group = 1 
AND customer = 12345";
```

**Edit**:

`var_dump($result)` says bool(false). Is this normal?

Comment: @de_nuit Added that and edited a bit.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT `chosen` FROM `choices` WHERE `group` = 1 AND `customer` = 12345";
Are group and customer INT-Fields?

Comment: Group is `varchar`but customer is `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, simple query in sql:

```
$group = 1;
$customer = 12345;

// @de_nuit we have the same idea :-D
$sql = "SELECT `chosen` FROM `choices` WHERE `group` = '".$group."' AND `customer` = '".$customer."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$p = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $p[$row['prod']] = true;
}
```

Maybe simply is create a small function?

```
function emptyCheck($p, $trick){
   // Your syntax to check
   if( isset($p[$trick]) ){
      if( $p[$trick] == true ){ echo "checked"; }
   }
}
```

Then use:

```
<input type="button" <?=emptyCheck($p,0)?> />
```

Now, it's old method, read this for more informations: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: If no choice has been made at all (empty sql result), wouldn't that trigger an offset error?

Comment: Ah, this eventually did the trick. Just had to add true/false to the function variables in order to check if it's the `yes` or `no` button that is checked.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<input type="button" <?=(empty($p[0]) || $empty === '0')?'':'checked';?> />
```

(check if it's empty or if it's value is 0 - not checked.)

or if it's only checked if it's a 1 :

EDIT

```
if($p[0]) {
 ?>
   <input type="button" <?=($p[0] === '1') ? 'checked':'';?> />
 <?
 }else {
   <input type="button" />
 }
?>
```

(check if it's value is 1 - checked)

Comment: I used the second one of those before, but that triggered offset errors since there sometimes wasn't any $p[x] due to empty sql result.

Comment: check the array exists before outputting the input button then see edit

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) `0` is considered to be `empty`

Comment: So is there a way to know the difference between a "0" in the db and an empty query result? Like if I check whether a product is 1, 0 or not in the table at all?

Comment: @harryg that's a good reason to avoid using empty() in this case then. This is easily done by checking strlen().

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT `chosen` FROM `choices` WHERE `group` = '1' AND `customer` = 12345";
```

You have to put a string in quotes.

If you are using Variables:

```
$sql = "SELECT `chosen` FROM `choices` WHERE `group` = '".$group."' AND `customer` = ".$customer;
```

Edit:

You might have a mysql_query(); somewhere. Add a die method. You can the see if your requests threw any errors. if so post them to your answer.

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I've tried the query that doesn't return anything in an external db manager (Sequel Pro) and that just says 0 results, no errors. I'd guess that should clear any case of errors.